# Javascript redirect on form submit depending on input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a simple javascript quiz, and I can't for the life of me get Javascript to submit the form and open the result in the same page, regardless of whether I use location.href, open.window, or whether I set "_self" as the target. Doesn't seem to matter what I do...

```js
function answer() {
  var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
  if (response == "correctanswer")
    location.href('right.html');
  else
    location.href('wrong.html');
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="answer()" id="answer" target="_self">
  <input type="text" maxlength="55" class="box" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

So, what I want to happen is, when the user submits the form, they go to "right.html" if they typed *correctanswer* into the text box, or "wrong.html" if they typed anything else.

I've got it running fine, except for the fact that no matter what I do I can't get the resulting page to open in `_self`, but rather in another window. Every time.

Been driving me crazy all night.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Five things:

1. Remove the `target` attribute of `form` entirely. The default is the same window. Although it doesn't really matter, because:
2. Cancel the `submit` event by returning `false` in your `onSubmit`, since you're handling the form in your own code. One easy way to do this is have your function return `false`, and in the `onSubmit`, return the result of the call.
3. This line is incorrect:

   ```
   var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
   ```

   `form` elements don't have a `value`. You'd want to put the `id` on the `input type="text"` element instead.
4. The `href` on `location` is not a function, it's a property. You just assign to it (or just assign directly to `location`).
5. This one's a bit subtle: Because you have a global function called `answer`, and you have an element with an `id` `"answer"`, there's a conflict: Both want to end up as properties of the `window` object (one of many reasons not to use old DOM0 `onxyz` attributes — or global functions, come to that). So you need to change the name of one of them, e.g., change the function to `checkAnswer` or similar.

So:

```
<form onSubmit="return checkAnswer();">
<input id="answer" type="text" maxlength="55" class="box" autofocus />
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

And:

```
function checkAnswer(){
    var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    if (response == "correctanswer")
        location = 'right.html';
    else
        location = 'wrong.html';
    return false;
}
```

Full Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ifupix/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ifupix/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form onSubmit="return checkAnswer();">
  <input id="answer" type="text" maxlength="55" class="box" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
  <script>
  function checkAnswer(){
      var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
      if (response == "correctanswer")
          location = 'http://jsbin.com/ukifoh/1'; // 'right.html';
      else
          location = 'http://jsbin.com/ukifoh/2'; // 'wrong.html';
      return false;
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I would recommend always using consistent, useful code indentation, and I'm a big fan of always using blocks, not just statements, with control structures.

Comment: Wow! Thanks much for all the help clearing up my murky code! And for the speedy reply!