# url action in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can write this on javascript. 
This is on html form.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("NewPage")" >
 ....
</form>
```

Now I have javascript function.

```
function validateForm() {
     //var x = document.forms["form"]["fname"].value;
     var x = document.getElementById('id').value;
     if (x == null || x == 0 || x == "0") {
         alert("stop");
         return false;
     }
     else {
         document.form.submit();


     }
}
```

What should be in the html form action.

Comment: Write this in JavaScript where? What are you asking?

Comment: <a href="NewPage.html">Click event for page</a>. Normally this is used to navigate to new html page. Please provide more details about your requirement.

Comment: Hello, asp.net MVC... Is that you there, not being tagged?

Comment: I update. Here is function.

Comment: ok,you want that in else condition?

Comment: Is there a particular function or page that you want to re-direct to on success?

Comment: @VAGABOND yes. In else.

Comment: @NejcGalof:check my answer and this link also...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007010/javascript-redirect-on-form-submit-depending-on-input

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It now looks like you want to have your HTML form redirect to another page on submit. To accomplish that, do this:

```
<form action="newurl.php" method="post">
[...]
</form>
```

where `newurl.php` is whatever page you want to submit to.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

If you want to use javascript to change the url, which is what it looks like you want to do, use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    location.href="http://new.url/whatever";
</script>
```

If you want to do it on a button-press, wrap it in a function and have the button call the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newURL(url) {
    location.href=url;
}
</script>
<input type='button' value='Google' onclick="newURL('http://google.com')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirection,Use any these

```
    - alert(document.URL)

    - alert(Window.location.href)

    - alert(document.location.href)
```

So to redirect,use this function and call it appropriately:

```
 function validateForm() {
 //var x = document.forms["form"]["fname"].value;
 var x = document.getElementById('id').value;
 if (x == null || x == 0 || x == "0") {
     alert("stop");
     return false;
 }
 else {
     document.form.submit();
     Window.location.href="www.google.com";//redirect on form submit
 }
```

}

Note:If you have an action page,then give it a header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
action='@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoRedirect() {
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
</script>
```