# Auto-fill specific login forms of a external webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to pass credentials to fill automatically the inputs login of this website: https://www.pinterest.pt/login/  .
I don't know what are the variables. So I used the inspect of the browser to know what is the id of each input.

I'm using this code but it is not working:

```js
 function Test() {
    var name = document.getElementById("id").value;

    var password= document.getElementById("password").value;

    document.forms["registerForm"].submit();  //form submission
 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form id="registerForm" name="registerForm" method="post" target="_top" action="https://www.pinterest.pt/login/">

    <input id="email" name="id" type="email" value="examplelogin"  />
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="examplepassword" />

    <input type="button" name="submit" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="Test()" />

    </form>
   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just modified your code. you put / in the end of form tag. That's why it didn't work. Now please check again. If any changes let me know.

Comment: you have to add response.redirect('https://www.pinterest.pt/login/') in test().

Comment: When I run your suggestion, the code gives this error: 
Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 27,
  "colno": 45
}. For response.redirect you suggest do like this? :

    <script>
    function Test() {
    var name = document.getElementById("id").value;

    var password= document.getElementById("password").value;

    document.forms["registerForm"].submit();  //form submission
    
    response.redirect("pinterest.pt/login/");
 
    }
</script>

Comment: Wait let me check.

Comment: Use this window.location.href="https://www.pinterest.pt/login/" in test().

Comment: Like this?     <script>
    function Test() {
    var name = document.getElementById("id").value;

    var password= document.getElementById("password").value;

    document.forms["registerForm"].submit();  //form submission
    
    window.location.href="pinterest.pt/login";
 
    }
    </script>. This is not working yet. How I put correctly the response.redirect("pinterest.pt/login/");?

Comment: Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007010/javascript-redirect-on-form-submit-depending-on-input

Comment: I have added the code. Please Check.

Comment: you can't bring username and password to online websites for login.

Comment: Yes, the reason is because the website generates a CSRF token. Now I'm trying to use a API of a password manager software to fill automatically the input credentials. Anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer to your question, but more of a future reference, you don't *need* to get all elements within a form via a selector. You can simply use the following technique:

```
function Test() {
    let form = document.getElementById('registerForm');
    var password = form.elements.password.value; 
    var email = form.elements.email.value;
    form.submit();
}
```

Notice how accessing `form.elements` grants direct access to the `element` you're trying to read out.

Comment: I also tried use your technique but the pinterest opened with error:  pinterest.com/csrf_error. It is really possible fill an input of a webpage that I don't developed with Javascript?

Comment: Well no. The reason you're getting that error is because pinterest generates a CSRF token for each user as a way to prevent XSS.

Comment: Ok. I also tried to use the website https://www.allianz.pt/area-privada to fill their credentials with Javascript. In this case this website didn´t return the error but didn't fill the username and password input. I have the code below. Is it possible for this website use javascript to fill the credentials? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well you cant fill in a form from another site, but you CAN send a post request to the URL the form on that website is sending it's data to. But as I said, most sites use tokens to check if the sender is actually on their site and a legit users. That's why we use API calls nowadays. Maybe the pinterest API provides in what you want to achieve?

Comment: This question can be stupid but How can I use a pinterest API to do what I need? For exemple for allianz I found this: https://openapi.allianz-assistance.com/#default/gallery. What I would like to do is the same thing that a password manager software like EnPass does: the user just need to insert the url, the user and the password and the software fills the credentials inputs correctly. Do you know what this software or other uses to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use Lastpass for that as well. What you're trying to do is store user login credentials (probably localStorage) and allow a user to use it. This means your Javaacript will have to run on all pages a user visits, which is impossible. If your goal is to create a Lastpass-like application, you should be making a browser extension.

Comment: Yes what I'm trying to do is store user login credentials and allow a user to use it. I developed a app and what I want is to add in the app the functionality of clicking a webpage link, their credentials are automatically filled. The credentials are saved in database of the app. Is it possible use a api of EnPass or LastPass to do that?

Comment: No, they&#39;re self-sustained apps. The functionality you want to write simply impossible in Javascript due to browser-based security. The only other solution you might have any success with, is building a vanilla Android or iOS app that &quot;wrap around&quot; a Webview and monitor it for changes and inject/subtract data.

Comment: Ok but my app is a web application not a mobile app. I find that keepass has a API: https://keepass.info/help/v2_dev/scr_sc_index.html . Do you know if with the information that exist in this website I can develop a api for keepass? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I may just be nit-picking, but since this is a form submit, you probably need to use `onsubmit` and not just have the button click do something. Try this maybe?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" target="_top" action="https://www.allianz.pt/area-privada" onsubmit="submitFunction()">

<input id="usuario" name="_58_login" type="text" value="examplelogin" />
<input id="password" name="_58_password" type="password" value="examplepassword" />

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<script>

function Test() {
    // your submit code
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Forms can be very picky sometimes. Always best to use a working example for exactly what you're doing as a reference.

Comment: I tried run the code with your suggestion but when the allianz.pt/area-privada opens, it just thinks and don't show the whole page.

Comment: @john3485 Make sure you are sending all the correct data with your form submit, there should be specific parameters that are required to view what you need to see that you may not be providing.

Comment: The problem is the website generates a CSRF token.